# How to assemble tokens into an array based on the their position in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string and two arrays of tokens in the order they are placed in the string:

```
var str = `abc TOKEN_EXPRESSION TOKEN_OPERATOR textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR`;

var expressions = [
    'z1',
    'f3'
];

var operators = [
    '+',
    'OR'
];
```

In the end, I want to get one array containing expression and operator tokens alongside simple text in the order they appear in the string. So the result should look like that:

```
['abc ', 'z1', ' ', '+', ' text', 'f3', 'OR']
```

At the moment, my approach is to work with the string, search for either `TOKEN_EXPRESSION` or `TOKEN_OPERATOR` and cut the beginning of the string step by step. So it works like this now:

```
found   remaining string
--------------------------
'abc'   'TOKEN_EXPRESSION TOKEN_OPERATOR textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR'
'z1'    ' TOKEN_OPERATOR textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR'
' '     'TOKEN_OPERATOR textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR'
'+'     ' textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR'
```

But I feel there's gotta to be a better, easier to understand and more efficient way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your existing code look like? I'd hate to suggest the same thing as you're already doing...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, it's a multiple for loops cutting beginning of the string away step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be easier to use `replace` method and its groups' flags feature:

```
// Initialize two separate counters
var exc = 0, opc = 0;

// Replace each found group with corresponding value
result = str.replace(/TOKEN_(?:(EXPRESSION)|(OPERATOR))/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return "$$" + (p1 ? expressions[exc++] : operators[opc++]) + "$$"
});

// Split on delimiters
console.log(result.split("$$").filter(String))
```

Output:

```
["abc ", "z1", " ", "+", " text ", "f3", "OR"]
```

Comment: thanks, why do you use non-capturing group? Is it to group together `(EXPRESSION)` and `(OPERATOR)` ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var     str = `abc TOKEN_EXPRESSION TOKEN_OPERATOR textTOKEN_EXPRESSIONTOKEN_OPERATOR`,
expressions = ['z1','f3'],
  operators = ['+', 'OR'],
     result = str.split(/TOKEN_(EXPRESSION|OPERATOR)/)
                 .reduce((p,c) => (c && (c === "EXPRESSION" ? p.push(expressions.shift())
                                                            : c === "OPERATOR" ? p.push(operators.shift())
                                                                               : p.push(c)), p),[]);
console.log(result);
```